# When using py2app, is there a way to customize the traceback dialog that gets displayed? (Or show a different Cocoa dialog?)

Tags: python, macos, py2app

Is there an easy way to get any more control over the py2app traceback dialogs, or just a nice way to display GUI messages?

If I raise an exception in my py2app script, I get a dialog that says something like this:

> **MyAppName Error**
>
> MyAppName Error
>
> An unexpected error has occurred during execution of the main script
>
> MyRaisedError: This is the text that I can control when I raise the error.

It has *Open Console* and *Terminate* buttons. My script needs to check if a certain DVD is in the drive, if it's not, I want to show an error dialog and quit. I would like to have more control over it than this, as I can only change some of the text and can't control the buttons.

I tried calling osascript to do 'display dialog' via applescript, but it gave me an error like this: 0:19: execution error: No user interaction allowed. (-1713) I don't particularly like this way of doing it, but if it's all I can do...

I would really prefer not to include a big project like [Cocoa Dialogs](http://cocoadialog.sourceforge.net/) or something like a PyObjC project... the script itself is very tiny and I can't see adding 10x the meat of my script just to get the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `osascript`, you can call `display dialog` via [py-appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc/osax-manual/03_examples.html) which, if you don't already have it in your python site-library, can be installed via `easy_install`.  This example works inside of a py2app-generated app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from osax import *
import py2app

def doit():
    sa = OSAX()
    sa.display_dialog("Python says hello!",
            buttons=["Hi!", "Howdy!", "Duuuude!"],
            default_button=3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doit()
```

Comment: What's the best way to include that in the py2app bundle? I don't want people using my app to have to install it.

Comment: By importing it in your script, py2app should automatically include in your app bundle.  You don't have to do anything special.

Comment: To clarify though, py2app won't necessarily do that if you are using the default Apple-supplied python.  For a stand-alone app that you are going to distribute and that you might want to work on multiple levels of OS X, you probably want to be using a python.org python.

Comment: This is only going to run on 10.6 (really!)  The way it automatically bundles in imported stuff is really creepy, but awesome. I can't find osax files anywhere in the built package...

Answer (score 0):

Just put a standard Python try/catch block around the section of code that throws the exception, then use NSAlert to tell your users they need to put the DVD in

Comment: Where does NSAlert come from?